# jstl <c:when> tag wrong result

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
<c:set var="pageCount" value="16"></c:set>
<c:set var="maxSugguestPage" value="7"></c:set>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${pageCount < maxSugguestPage}"> <!-- why this block executed? -->
        <c:forEach begin="1" end="${pageCount}" var="index">
            <li><a href="#">${index }</a></li>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="firstDot" value="true"></c:set>
        <c:forEach begin="1" end="${pageCount - 1}" var="index">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${index > maxSugguestPage and firstDot == true}">
                <li><a href="#">..</a></li>
                <c:set var="firstDot" value="false"></c:set>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:if test="${firstDot == true}">
                    <li><a href="#">${index }</a></li>
                </c:if>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
        <li><a href="#">${pageCount }</a></li>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

this is a `jsp` file using `jstl`,but there are some problem with the tag `<c:when>`.
I declare two variables called `pageCount` and `maxSuggestPage`, it's very obvious `pageCount > maxSugguestPage`, but when using `<c:when test="${pageCount < maxSuggestPage}">`, the code block in it executed and the `<c:otherwise>` block not.

Comment: view your page source and check the value of pageCount and sugguestPage and also check the value of {pageCount < maxSugguestPage} you may get some hint.

Comment: Yuck! What a mess!!! So much logic in a JSP

Comment: i want to do the paging but i don't know how to write simply:>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the values as strings, not as numbers. Those strings are [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) compared.

Set them as numbers instead.

```xml
<c:set var="pageCount" value="${16}" />
<c:set var="maxSugguestPage" value="${7}" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, it's unnecessary to compare a boolean expression to a fixed boolean value in a boolean statement like so `${firstDot == true}`. Just use the boolean expression right away like so `${firstDot}`.

Comment: thank u, it's no problem now.And `<c:set var="firstDot" value="true"></c:set>` must be written as `<c:set var="firstDot" value="{true}"></c:set>` ?

Comment: No, you don't need the braces.   You can set it to "true" and it will get converted based on the context of using it as an expression.

Comment: If you have a new question, press "Ask Question" button on right top.